# Show only Months with Events In them?

Tags: fullcalendar

Would there be a way to limit the next/prev buttons to only show months with events registered in them? We have courses that fill up and I don't want users to have to fast forward through blank months where there is no availability of events.  I'm also including holiday events from the basic google public holidays calendar and don't want to include those events.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, this option does not exist in FullCalendar yet.

**If you are retrieving events month by month:**
You can bind fullcalendar's Next and Previous events to a new function. Inside this function, get the events and if there is no events, your function must call Next or Previous again.

**If you are retrieving all events at once**
You can bind fullcalendar's Next and Previous events to a new function. Inside this function, get all the events and look for the first date out of the current month. Set fullcalendar's current date for that month and refresh it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try these suggestions! :-)